# How to get the uploaded file path?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am using input tag `type="file"` to browse the file in asp.net.

I browsed the file "Linq2sql.zip" from the location "c\Desktop\Karthik\Linq2sql.zip".

i can get the file name and path using

```
HttpPostedFileBase file;
var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
```

But File path is like = `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevServer\\10.0\\Linq2sql.zip`

i have to get the original file path `c\\Desktop\\Karthik\\Linq2sql.zip`. How can i get?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the original path of the file on the client system; that information is not sent by the client.

The reason you get what you do with GetFullPath is because that forces a resolution with the simple file name alone with the current directory of the asp.net process. That info is utterly meaningless - and in fact incorrect - in this case.

Comment: but how is it possible to get  original file path c\\Desktop\\Karthik\\Linq2sql.zip ???

Comment: @JayMagwadiya That information is *not* sent, as my answer said. This is for security - you would not want the browser to send this information, and no browser does.